# .NET CORE Authentication Policy OR

Tags: .net, .net-core, jwt

I would like to use an or statement for a policy

E.g.

My controller should be accessible when a user with a role OR an API with a scope tries to access;

```
options.AddPolicy("Api", policy => policy.RequireClaim("scope", "api01"));

options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireRole("admin"));
```

is this possible without having both the scope and the user role in the token?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Did not see the OR. So, the way I see it you could solve it by using custom handler requirement. For example, you can create the following classes

```
public class Api01ScopeRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public Api01ScopeRequirement()
    {
    }
}

public class CustomAuthHandler : AuthorizationHandler<Api01ScopeRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
                                                   Api01ScopeRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "api01") || context.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And in your startup you can add

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Api01Scope", policy =>
      policy.Requirements.Add(new Api01ScopeRequirement()));
});
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1 for further reference.